# join the files of a folder under the same array

Tags: node.js

I want to get the files with the same folder into the same array

Here is my code :

```
const pathFile = [
  'modules/main/main1/main.js',
  'modules/server/server1/server.js',
  'modules/server/server2/server.js',
];

pathFile.forEach((p) => {
  const middle = p.split(/\//g);
  middle.pop();
  const fileFolder = middle[Math.floor(middle.length - 1) / 2];
  array.push({ folder: fileFolder, files: { name: p } });
});
```

This is the result i get :

```
[
  { "folder": "main", "files": { "name": "modules/main/main1/main.js" } },
  {
    "folder": "server",
    "files": { "name": "modules/server/server1/server.js" }
  },
  {
    "folder": "server",
    "files": { "name": "modules/server/server2/server.js" }
  }
]
```

Comment: Sorry there was a mistake, i just updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `reduce` into an object indexed by the `folder`, creating the associated `folder` object if needed, push to the `files` array, then get that object's values:

```js
const pathFile = [
  'modules/main/main1/main.js',
  'modules/server/server1/server.js',
  'modules/server/server2/server.js',
];
const obj = pathFile.reduce((a, name) => {
  const folder = name.split('/')[1];
  if (!a[folder]) {
    a[folder] = { folder, files: [] };
  }
  a[folder].files.push({ name });
  return a;
}, {});
const arr = Object.values(obj);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: thank you, it worked for me. but what if, if i want to turn it into an async function

Comment: Which function? Regardless, there are no asynchronous operations here, so there's no need for it.

Comment: because i need to do a treatment for each file retreived right after it, so i can just add the foreach without any probleme?

Comment: `forEach` isn't asynchronous, so there shouldn't be any need for it. If the operation you need *is* asynchronous, the code will be notably more complicated.

Comment: no i know that it's not asynchronous, but after i understood your point, i wanted to ask you how can now loop through each of those files and do treatment on them

Comment: You can either put the mechanism inside the `reduce` (eg `files.push(doSomething({ name }))`, or you can iterate over the array afterwards, eg `arr.forEach(({ files }) => files.forEach((file) => /* do something with file */`